# Filter for email addresses with which I have corresponded

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I'd like to create a search filter in Gmail which filters my inbox for emails received from addresses I have sent mail to.

Is there a way to do this, perhaps through a custom search query?